# VB.NET HtmlAgilityPack scraping text

Tags: vb.net, xpath

I want to use HtmlAgilityPack to scrape content from https://steamid.io/, specifically, I want to scrape the status of the user's "Online Status".

I can correctly scrape the information I need using XPath, but.. Each user's profile is different there for the XPath changes, only slightly.

**If the user's profile is "private" the XPath is**

`/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/dl/dd[9]`

**If the users profile is not "private" the XPath is**

`/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/dl/dd[9]/span`

How would I be able to make HtmlAgilityPack check which div it is that I want to display, as I can set my own profile to private and unprivate but obviously I need to change the XPath accordingly to be able to show the status.

If i use the XPath containing the `/span` and the user's profile is private I get
`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

If i un-private the profile and use the `/span` XPath is works fine and shows me what I want.

Here is my entire code

````
'Online Status - from steamid.io
        Dim curOnline = idIo.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/dl/dd[9]/span")
        'Dim curOnline2 = idIo.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/dl/dd[9]")

        For Each node In curOnline
            onlinelbl.Text = node.InnerText
            If node.InnerText.ToString().Contains("private") Then
                onlinelbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
                onlinelbl.Text = "Private"
            ElseIf onlinelbl.Text.Contains("away") Then
                onlinelbl.Text = onlinelbl.Text.Replace("away", "Away")
                onlinelbl.ForeColor = Color.Orange
            ElseIf onlinelbl.Text.Contains("online") Then
                onlinelbl.Text = onlinelbl.Text.Replace("online", "Online")
                onlinelbl.ForeColor = Color.Green
            ElseIf onlinelbl.Text.Contains("offline") Then
                onlinelbl.Text = onlinelbl.Text.Replace("offline", "Offline")
                onlinelbl.ForeColor = Color.Red
            End If
        Next
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply look for the existence of the XPath with `/span`:

```
    Dim curOnline As HtmlNodeCollection
    curOnline = idIo.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/dl/dd[9]/span")
    If curOnline Is Nothing Then
        curOnline = idIo.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/section/dl/dd[9]")
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, when using your above code it gives me an error 
```Error BC30311 Value of type 'HtmlNodeCollection' cannot be converted to 'XmlNodeList'.
```

Comment: Just change the type of `curOnline` to `HtmlNodeCollection` then

Comment: That seems to have worked fine. Thank you for your help.